# How to prevent messages from a Google Group going to the Spam folder?

Tags: gmail, google-groups, spam-prevention

I use a Google Group to manage a large course, with many students and teachers. Last year it worked fine. But this year, I noticed that most messages sent by students to the group address, are marked as "Spam" by the Gmail account of me and the other staff members.

I can solve the problem for myself by creating a filter for this specific group, with action "Never send it to spam". But then, I also have to explain to all the other group members (more than 200) to do the same, which is quite time-consuming.

Is there a way to "white-list" a google group, so that Gmail's spam filter does not classify it automatically as spam?

Comment: Are the students members of the group or only staff members? Does the students joined by themselves or you sent an invitation? All of you are using consumer accounts, all are using workspace accounts or a mix of them?

Comment: Students are members of the group. They join by themselves using the group link. We all use personal email accounts (mostly gmail).

Comment: I have the same issue but I haven't find any solution to it yet.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent emails from going to spam folders in Gmail, have them add the email to their contacts. See instructions here: [Report spam in Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1366858?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) (Gmail Support).

Comment: Does this really work for groups? It sounds like the emails are coming from an open group using all sorts of personal email addresses, which means you would constantly have to be checking spam to see if someone new sent something.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what Google says:

Relax a group’s spam controls

1. Sign in to Google Groups.
2. Click the name of a group.
3. On the left, click Group settings and then Posting policies.
4. Under Spam message handling, select Post suspicious messages to the group.
5. Click Save changes.

Comment: The OP wants to avoid recipient accounts labeling the group messages as SPAM.  Your solution will not improve the situation.  If anything it will make it worse.  The [information you provided](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2567001) is to avoid suspicious messages being diverted to the **Group administrator's** moderation queue.  Messages sent to this queue are not delivered to group members unless first reviewed by the administrator.  An entirely different issue.